# Running SQL statement with wrong quote style

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a query in phpMyAdmin but it's not working due to an issue with quotations. The values in my table are specifying inches, such as 4", 6", etc. My query is setting a number to a field based on the value in that size column but it's not running because in the current format it thinks the values for inches are columns due to the single quote.

How can I run this in phpMyAdmin if all the values already have " at the end of the value?

```
UPDATE `stagingSurvey`
SET `totalCost` = 330
WHERE `meterSize` = `3"`
OR `meterSize` = `4"`
OR `meterSize` = `5"`
OR `meterSize` = `6"`
OR `meterSize` = `7"`
OR `meterSize` = `8"`
OR `meterSize` = `9"`
OR `meterSize` = `10"`
OR `meterSize` = `11"`
OR `meterSize` = `12"`;

UPDATE `stagingSurvey`
SET `totalCost` = 175
WHERE `meterSize` = `5/8"`
OR `meterSize` = `3/4"`
OR `meterSize` = `1"`
OR `meterSize` = `1 1/2"`
OR `meterSize` = `2"`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use backticks to escape the column values / string values. Backticks are only valid to escape identifiers (like column and table names).

> The identifier quote character is the backtick (`).
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

In your case you are using `"` in string values so you can't directly use `"` to escape the string values. A simple solution would be to use `'` instead of backticks.

You can also use `"` to escape the string values, but you have to escape the `"` on values: `\"`.

> A string is a sequence of bytes or characters, enclosed within either single quote (') or double quote (") characters.
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html

In your case you can simply use `'` to escape the string values:

```
UPDATE `stagingSurvey`
SET `totalCost` = 330
WHERE `meterSize` = '3"'
    OR `meterSize` = '4"'
    OR `meterSize` = '5"'
    OR `meterSize` = '6"'
    OR `meterSize` = '7"'
    OR `meterSize` = '8"'
    OR `meterSize` = '9"'
    OR `meterSize` = '10"'
    OR `meterSize` = '11"'
    OR `meterSize` = '12"';

UPDATE `stagingSurvey`
SET `totalCost` = 175
WHERE `meterSize` = `5/8"`
    OR `meterSize` = '3/4"'
    OR `meterSize` = '1"'
    OR `meterSize` = '1 1/2"'
    OR `meterSize` = '2"';
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I've just realized.  Up until now, I've been able to use double quotes around my values but these values in the table all have a double quote after to denote inches. What would be the proper way to surround these values?

Comment: To clarify, strings should be delimited with `'` not with `\``. An embedded double quote in a string `'1"'` shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. I didn't pay attention to the single quote/backtick issue. This is perfect!